# UWP: DataPackageView Bug

Tags: javascript, class, winapi, uwp, windows-store-apps

The Docs for the [`Clipboard` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.clipboard#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_Clipboard_GetContent) state, that the `getContent()` Method returns a [`DataPackageView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview) object. So far so good.

The following works:

```
var containsString = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().contains(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.text)
```

`containsString` equals true.

The following does not work:

```
var text = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().getTextAsync();
var text = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().getTextAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.text);
var text = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().getHtmlFormatAsync();
var text = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().getDataAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.text);
```

Each methods are listed in the above linked Doc for `DataPackageView`, all returning an empty object after checking `contains(...)`.

This also does not work:

```
var results = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().requestAccessAsync();
var results = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().requestAccessAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.text);
var results = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().unlockAndAssumeEnterpriseIdentity();
```

... all returning nothing.

Is that because these methods are asynchronous? Do I need a timeout?

I've literally tried everything. What am I doing wrong, or is this this a bug with the `getContent()` method or the `DataPackageView`?

Comment: Please see [Asynchronous patterns in UWP using JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps#asynchronous-patterns-in-uwp-using-javascript).

Comment: @IInspectable Could you please explain what that means regarding this problem. I've never dealt with translating Async patterns to js before.

Comment: It means that you have to translate asynchronous patterns to JavaScript. There's no way for you to write **any** UWP app without understanding how asynchronous operations are projected into your preferred environment. You cannot evade asynchronous code, because UWP makes abundant use of it.

Comment: So to summarize, your point is the same as suggested in the given answer by @DaveSmits below. Am I right?

Comment: @IInspectable In addition I did not say, that I don't understand asynchronous patterns. I just mentioned that I never used them in javascript before.

Comment: Not really. My point is, that you need to learn how to fish. But if you are happy with someone just handing you the fish, then yes, you *can* use the `Promise.then` method. Depending on the circumstances, `Promise.done` may be more appropriate, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you for helping me - that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first sample you are not calling an async method. In all the other cases you do. i don't have visual studio right here so cant try it out but it should like something like this:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent().getTextAsync().then(function(result){
// result should be the text you are expecting
});
```

Comment: Propably I missunderstood you, but the following returns an empty Object: `var content = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard.getContent(); var text = content.getTextAsync().then(function(result){
            $('abc').text(text);
        });`